# Is it possible to pass data from AngularJS to a function with a model parameter in webservice?

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs, web-services

I want to know if it is possible to pass data from AngularJS to a function with a model parameter in webservice?

Here is my webservice code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void AddUser(
    //string FirstName, string LastName, string Mi //this works
    User user //not working
    )
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=########;Initial Catalog=test001;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=########;Password=########");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[User] values(@fname,@lname,@mi)", con);

    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", user.FirstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", user.LastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mi", user.Mi);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Here is my angularJS code:

```
$scope.Create = function () {
    var user = {
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.LastName,
        Mi: $scope.Mi
    };

    $http.post('testws.asmx/AddUser', user, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    });
}
```

Comment: I guess you should send the parameters seperately(firstName, lastName, mi), and create your `User` object in your service method.

Comment: so it means, it is not possible? @TolgaEvcimen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty doable. At worst case, you can extract parameters from `Request.Form` in your service method like this.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void AddUser()
{
    /// here you get your json object from post data
    var serializedUser = Request.Form["user"] as string;
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(serializedUser);

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=172.16.176.74;Initial Catalog=test001;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=onbapps;Password=sdu_123456");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[User] values(@fname,@lname,@mi)", con);

    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", user.FirstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", user.LastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mi", user.Mi);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

So it is possible, but I'm sure there exist much neater ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

In Service or factory you can write like

```
var promise = $http({
url: "testws.asmx/AddUser"+ "/Post",
method: "POST",
data: user
});
return promise;
```